# Getting an IOException when running a sample code in "Mahout in Action"

Tags: java, exception, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I'm learning Mahout and reading "Mahout in Action". When I tried to run the sample code in chapter7 SimpleKMeansClustering.java, an exception popped up:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: wrong value class: 0.0: null is not class org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedPropertyVectorWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:1874)
    at SimpleKMeansClustering.main(SimpleKMeansClustering.java:95)

Does anyone have any idea about this exception? I have been trying to solve it for a long time and haven't got any idea. And there are few sources on the internet.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an IOException when running a sample code in “Mahout in Action” on mahout-0.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565998/getting-an-ioexception-when-running-a-sample-code-in-mahout-in-action-on-mahou)

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered on the Manning list. There is a bad input file in there somewhere: a stray file (like "_SUCCESS"), or you're pointing at the wrong directory, or the input is indeed not in the right format.